# Cluster office workstations when not in use?

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, cluster, windows-cluster

We've got around ~15 relatively decent Windows machines in the office and I'm wondering if it's possible to set up a system that clusters them as a single virtual machine when they're not in use during office hours.

We run a lot of CPU intensive numerical simulations and rather than buying standalone simulation machines, it'd be nice to leverage the unused office workstations at night/over the weekend (ideally as a single VM with many CPUs).

If this is possible, where would one start looking to go about this? Are there any common issues/considerations I should be aware of?

Thanks.

Comment: I would look at the software you use to run those simulations and the platforms that are supported. Maybe you're lucky and there's something that can be installed if not on top of windows, then as a secondary OS, for istance.

Comment: Possible, yes, but it would be amazingly inconvenient for the office workers.